# How to replace the classes of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations for .NET Standard?

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

.NET Standard did not support 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations', and 'System.Type.Properties', how to keep compatible with it ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The types from the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace are in [the `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/), which is not installed by default in a .Net Standard library, so you need to install it manually to use it there.

If you mean `Type.GetProperties()`, then that method exists as an extension method in .Net Core and in .Net Standard. In a .Net Standard library, you will need to install [the `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions/). In both a .Net Core application and a .Net Standard library, you will need to add `using System.Reflection;` to your source.